# JAVARDD.saveAsTextFile() results in Mkdirs failed to create for half of the directory on local disc using Spark 3.3.2 with hadoop 3.3.2

Tags: apache-spark

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/var/backup/dumpfiles/main/REPORT/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20230418102042734607451367455235_0005_m_000017_3 (exists=false, cwd=file:/opt/spark-3.3.2/work/app-20230418102040-0000/2)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:113)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2291)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
```

Writing data on local disc successfully using Spark3.3.2 and Hadoop2 .

When Hadoop versions is changed to 3.3.2 with spark 3.3.2. getting MKDIR issue. *your text*